# Client side validation is working but passing Null values to the controller in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

**Client side validation is not working...**
same process I have done in another page its working but there have not used forloop.
Here when I type the text without doing the validation simply tick image is displaying... give me solution..

View is

```
 @model IList<clientval.Models.ShoppingClass>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home"))
        {
            for (int i =0; i <1; i++)
            {


        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("FirstName")</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("FirstName")<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o[i].FirstName)</div></td>
        <td>@Html.Label("LastName")</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("LastName")<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o[i].LastName)</div></td>
        <tr>
        }
        }
```

Script is

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../assets/js/ClientScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Controller is

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult Guestlogin(string firstname, string lastname)
        {

              ShoppingClass s = new ShoppingClass();
              var button = Request["button"];
              var ob = s.Newcustomer(customerfirstname, customerlastname);
             TempData["BN"] = ob;
            return RedirectToAction("Sucessfully", ob);

        }
```

Model is

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "First Name is Not valid")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is Required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Last Name is Not valid")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<ShoppingClass> Newcustomer(string firstname, string lastname)
        {

            List<ShoppingClass> list = new List<ShoppingClass>();
            ShoppingClass obj = new ShoppingClass();
.
.
.
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're doing with the `for`-loop, but I'm guessing that's just an example?

Shouldn't you be using TextBoxFor and LabelFor like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home"))
        {
            for (int i =0; i <1; i++)
            {


        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(o => o[i].FirstName)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o[i].FirstName)<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o[i].FirstName)</div></td>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(o => o[i].LastName)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o[i].LastName)<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o[i].LastName)</div></td>
        <tr>
        }
        }
```

Comment: If I give like that means client side validation is working but values not storing into the database... and showing error like expects "parameter '@FirstName', which was not supplied."

Comment: Please show us the code that fails if you do the client-side of things correct, it might be the server-side code this is wrong?

Comment: I have entered the name in FirstName textbox and after clicked the submit button, it passing NULL value to the function..

Comment: How does the function look? what arguments does it take? The model and nothing else.

Comment: thiss is controller..public ActionResult Guestlogin(string firstname, string lastname). when i submit. it passing null value to the controller

Comment: That explains it, why are you not using the model as the only parameter? That's how model binding works (and client-side validation of the model). Maybe you should post the code of the model?

Comment: i am new..can u tell me how to post.. here or otherwise I have to ask new question by putting all the codes

Comment: Have you tried putting in the model as the only parameter to the action/function ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Html.Validate("FirstName");
```

Like this on all fields